# Cell Click event not fired when clicking in ag-grid column header

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am using ag-grid in pivot mode. For some reason when I click in a column group header the cell click event is not fired. It is fired correctly when I click in another other cell, including the row group headers.

Is there a separate event that gets fired when clicking in the column group headers I can handle?

Comment: Answer: **NO**.